# Magento 2.1 CLI install command failed: Base table or view not found

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I was trying to reinstall Magento in cli.

**I Ran this command**

```bash
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://local/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento \
--db-user=root --db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=Adminovich --admin-email=admin@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=qwerty --language=de_DE \
--currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Kiev \
--cleanup-database
```

And got

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `store_website` AS `main_table` ORDER BY main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC

[PDOException]                                                                                    
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.store_website' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Create a new database ands try again .`php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2git/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2git --db-user=root --db-password=admin#123 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1`  changes database and other parameters from here

Comment: @AmitBera I have created new database and got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to uninstall magento first. Cleared generated files (env.php and etc) and DB, then `setup:install`.

Answer (score 14):

If you are trying to install it over the same installation please try to uninstall it first.
As seen [on magento official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html):

```
/magento_root/bin/magento setup:uninstall
```

Then run your command again.

If this fails again then drop your database and re-run your commands as @Amit Bera already said.

Comment: trying to uninstall and got error 'Starting Magento uninstallation:
Can't clear cache due to the following error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table`
To fully clean up your uninstallation, you must manually clear your cache.' I have removed all from 'var'.

Comment: I think it was a fault that i didn't uninstall magento firstly.

Comment: If you haven't dropped your db yet try out /magento_root/bin/magento cache:clean and then the rest of the process.

Comment: I have re-cloned my project, drop database and got similar error. Trying to install from web interface and didn't got error.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting `/app/etc/env.php` fixes the problem. It will be regenerated by the `bin/magento setup:install` command.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the reason of this error. Some extensions add custom CLI commands.
Check di.xml for:

```
Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface
Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList
```

The problem is these commands include classes that require data in tables. But you didn't install the system. For example, if you try to include *Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface* in your command class you will get error like:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `store_website`.* FROM `store_website` - skipping database cleanup
```

Try to remove custom extensions before an installation.

P.S. Tested on Magento 2.3.1.

Comment: yes, I've added some custom modules with `composer` to my Magento app before DB was created and I had this error on `setup:install`. thanks @mykhailo-shatilov

Comment: As per https://magegyver.de/base-table-view-not-found-installing-new-magento-2/ you could try to use a Proxy class for TimezoneInterface

Comment: That was the issue for me when trying to run integration tests. Thx @aeno for the clean fix!